# BaggingClassifier take all dataset each time

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm, python-3.5

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier, BaggingClassifier, RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X=np.random.rand(1000,2)
Y=[random.randint(0,1) for x in range(0,1000)]

svm=BaggingClassifier(SVC(kernel='rbf', random_state=123, gamma=.000001, C=100000, class_weight='balanced'), max_samples=1/5.0, n_estimators=5, n_jobs=-1,random_state=123)

classfier=svm.fit(X,Y)

print(len(svm.estimators_samples_))
print(len(svm.estimators_samples_[0]))# here I expect 0.05*400 samples. but the result is 1000.
```

In this code, I try to apply BaggingClassifier with SVM. Normally as discussed in the documentation of sckitlearn, the `max_samples` fix the maximal number of samples to be used for each estimators. However, I remark that each estimator (n_estimators=5) take all the dataset!!! Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svm.estimators_samples_[0]` will return an array equal to the length of the data. This array is populated with boolean values, those values equal to `True` are the data points used in the estimator (in terms of index value).

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier, BaggingClassifier, RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X=np.random.rand(1000,2)
Y=[random.randint(0,1) for x in range(0,1000)]

svm=BaggingClassifier(SVC(kernel='rbf', random_state=123, gamma=.000001, C=100000, class_weight='balanced'), max_samples=1/5.0, n_estimators=5, n_jobs=-1,random_state=123)

classfier=svm.fit(X,Y)

print(len([i for i in svm.estimators_samples_[0] if i == True]))
```

Running the above code I get:

```
181
```